# The initialization process is exceeding network timeout

Tags: branch.io

I have a network timeout set for my Branch initialization but so many times the initialization ends up taking 10 times longer than it should. I know this because my app is supposed to be on the Splash screen only as long as the initialization process because of deep-linking. How do I make it faster? Or is there a better way to handle deeplinking?

Answer (score 1):

The Branch initialization process involves sending a network request and then waiting for a response, so this is always going to take some time - normally the response time should be 2-3 seconds with a decent internet connection. 
I would suggest starting Branch's `initSession` as quickly as possible before any other code in the onStart() method of your Splash Activity and you should be able to reduce the time the splash page displays.

Also, by default, Branch will delay the install call (only the install and not any future opens/reinstalls) only for up to 1.5 seconds. We delay the install call in order to capture the install referrer string passed through Google Play, which increases attribution and deferred deep linking accuracy. We do not delay any other call, and the install call only occurs the first time a user opens your app.

If we receive the referrer string before 1.5 seconds, we will immediately fire the call, meaning this delay is up to 1.5 seconds, but not guaranteed to take that long.

If you’d like to optimize the first install call, simply paste the following code in your Application class, and we will not delay the first install call.

```
public final class CustomApplicationClass {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // initialize the Branch object
        Branch.setPlayStoreReferrerCheckTimeout(0);
        Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
    }
}
```